# How to Convert latitude and Longitude to Address by using Location Plugin in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, location

I'm using `Location` library to get the latitude and longitude
https://pub.dev/packages/location

```
Location location = new Location();
    var latitude = "";
    var longitude = "";
    LocationData _locationData;
    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    latitude = _locationData.latitude.toString();
    longitude = _locationData.longitude.toString();
```

But how can i convert this latitude and longitude to address.

Answer (score 1):

Use [geocoder](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder) :

```
final coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
first = addresses.first;
print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
```

Comment: [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) is a more up-to-date package, for example it implements null safety, which geocoder does not.

Comment: @Amir Hossein Rahmanzadeh This plugin is old and it is not a null safety. It will not work if i install this plugin.

Comment: @PeterKoltai The problem is if i use geocoding plugin and insert this code `List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);` then on upper side that is on location plugin it shows an error "The name 'Location' is defined in the libraries 'package:geocoding_platform_interface/src/models/location.dart' and 'package:location/location.dart'." & "Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports."

Comment: This happens when more packages define the same class. Simply do: `import '...' as something;` for one of the packages and then it will be prefixed, for example you can access its contents like `something.function...` etc.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I just did `import 'package:location/location.dart' as testLocation;`. Now i am getting new error if i put a cursor on `Location` .`Location location = new Location();` on this line getting error "The named parameter 'latitude' is required, but there's no corresponding argument." .

Comment: Now you need to replace Location with the name that you imported as, in this case `testLocation`

Comment: @MohammedNabil Not replace, add before, like `testLocation.Location()`;

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad @PeterKoltai

Comment: @PeterKoltai `testLocation.Location();
    var latitude;
    var longitude;
    testLocation.LocationData _locationData;
    _locationData = await testLocation.getLocation(); // this line is getting an error 
    latitude = _locationData.latitude;
    longitude = _locationData.longitude;`
.get Location getting error "The function 'getLocation' isn't defined"

Comment: @AmirHosseinRahmanzadeh Please read the documentation. `getLocation` is a method of `Location` class. So you have to save `Location` instance and call this method on it: `final myLocation = testLocation.Location();` and then `myLocation.getLocation()` will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/), which is a free open-source geocoding API. It's recommended to setup your own server, but you can use their public API if you abide by their [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/).